# Create 2d Array in Python Using For Loop Results

Tags: python, arrays

I run some code within a for loop.  I want to take the results from my loop and place them in a 2d array with 2 columns and as many rows as times I iterate the loop.  Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
 for i in range(10):

      'bunch of stuff'

      centerx = xc
      centery = yc
```

How can I save my values for `centerx` and `centery` in a 2d array with 2 columns and 10 rows?  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
listvals = []
for i in range(10):
    listvals.append((xc, yc))
mat_vals = np.vstack(listvals)
```

This will output an ndarray like this:

```
[[ 2  0]
 [ 3  1]
 [ 4  2]
 [ 5  3]
 [ 6  4]
 [ 7  5]
 [ 8  6]
 [ 9  7]
 [10  8]
 [11  9]]
```

Or this maybe is better:

```
import numpy as np
list_xc = []
list_yc = []
for i in np.arange(10): 
    list_xc.append(xc)
    list_yc.append(yc)
mat_xc = np.asarray(list_xc)
mat_yc = np.asarray(list_yc)
mat_f = np.column_stack((mat_xc, mat_yc))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
aList = []
for i in range(10):
    aList.append([xc, yc])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this comprehension,

```
[ [i, i*10] for i in range(5) ]
```

which delivers

```
[[0, 0], [1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30], [4, 40], [5, 50]]
```